Extension refuses to load the script due to CSP violation
I'm an SE user often chatting in the physics and math chat rooms.
Since yesterday, the Chrome extension SE mathjax hasn't been able
to render the mathjax formatted lines which I previously used to get properly
displayed. To be straightforward, I do not know anything about
how these things work and after clicking on one of the $...$ mathjax
lines in the chat, I inspected the element and found these two problems popped up, which seem to be the cause of the problem:


Now I searched what these messages stand for and see if I could find
any solution on SO, but unfortunately, I can't even interpret the
two answers to the two questions I found related to my problem. I
kind of intuitively get being discussed but not what I can do to
solve it. The link in the second image takes to a page of code, which I guess is probably the source code, which I obviously cannot interpret:
var stop = false;
var update = true;
var beatInterval = 5000;

MathJax =
{
    tex:
    {
        inlineMath:
        [
            [
                "$",
                "$"
            ]
        ],
        displayMath:
        [
            [
                "$$",
                "$$"
            ]
        ],
        processEscapes: true,
        noundefined:
        {
            color: "red",
            background: "#FFEEEE",
            size: "90%25"
        },
        packages:
        {
            '[+]':
            [
                'base',
                'enclose',
                'cancel',
                'mhchem'
            ]
        }
    },
    options:
    {
        ignoreHtmlClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno|last-message"
    },
    loader:
    {
        load:
        [
            '[tex]/enclose',
            '[tex]/cancel',
            '[tex]/mhchem'
        ]
    },
    startup:
    {
        pageReady: () =>
        {
            return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady().then(() =>
            {
                console.log("MathJax is loaded, initial typesetting is triggered");
            });
        }
    }
};

$('document').ready(() =>
{
    var popup =
`<div id="jax-popup-bg" class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 1000; opacity: 0.5; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
<div id="jax-popup" style="top: 50%; left: 50%; display: block; padding: 10px; position: fixed; width: 150px; z-index: 1001; margin-top: -93.5px; margin-left: -113px;" class="wmd-prompt-dialog">
    <div align="center">
        <b>MathJax</b>
        <br>

        Interval:
        <input type="text" id="jax-heartbeat" style="width: 80px; margin-left: 10px" title="In miliseconds" value="` + beatInterval + `"/>
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="jax-update" title="Use an ajax handler instead of a heartbeat">Update</input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="jax-disable" style="margin-left: 10px" title="Temporarily stops MathJax from updating">Disable</input>
    </div>

    <button id="jax-ok" class="button">Ok</button>
    <button id="jax-cancel" style="margin-left: 10px" class="button">Cancel</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Set the initial UI state from globals
        $("#jax-update").prop("checked", update);
        $("#jax-disable").prop("checked", stop);
        $("#jax-heartbeat").prop("disabled", !update || stop);
        $("#jax-update").prop("disabled", stop);

        // Register an onClick() event handler to the Add button
        $("#jax-ok").click(function()
        {
            // If the configured hearbeat timeout is a valid number and greater than 1 second,
            if ($.isNumeric($("#jax-heartbeat").val()) && parseInt($("#jax-heartbeat").val()) >= 1000)
            {
                // ... and we're configured to update automatically,
                if ($("#jax-update").prop("checked") && !$("#jax-disable").prop("checked"))
                {
                    // ... update the heartbeat timeout value
                    beatInterval = parseInt($("#jax-heartbeat").val());
                }

                // ... and we're enabled,
                if (!$("#jax-disable").prop("checked"))
                {
                    // ... set the global update value
                    update = $("#jax-update").prop("checked");
                }

                // set the global stop value
                stop = $("#jax-disable").prop("checked");

                // Finally, clean up the popup window
                $("#jax-popup").remove();
                $("#jax-popup-bg").remove();
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, let the user know the timeout value is not valid
                alert("Interval values must be numeric and no less than 1000");
            }
        });

        // Register an onClick() event handler to the canel button,
        $("#jax-cancel").click(function()
        {
            // ... to clean up the popup window
            $("#jax-popup").remove();
            $("#jax-popup-bg").remove();
        });

        // Register an onClick() event handler to the update checkbox,
        $("#jax-update").click(function()
        {
            // ... which enables or disables the heartbeat text box as needed
            $("#jax-heartbeat").prop("disabled", !$("#jax-update").prop("checked"));
        });

        // Register an onClick() event handler to the disable checkbox,
        $("#jax-disable").click(function()
        {
            // ... which enables or disables the heartbeat text box and update check box as needed
            $("#jax-heartbeat").prop("disabled", $("#jax-disable").prop("checked"));
            $("#jax-update").prop("disabled", $("#jax-disable").prop("checked"));
        });
    </script>
</div>`;

    // Create a script object to add the MathJax configuration
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.2/es5/tex-svg.js";

    // Add MathJax to the page
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    // Create MathJax button in the chat buttons list
    $('#chat-buttons').prepend('<button class="button" id="math-button">MathJax</button>');

    $('#math-button').click(function()
    {
        $('body').append(popup);
    });

    // Run first heartbeat
    beat();
});

$('html').ajaxComplete(() =>
{
    if(!update && !stop)
    {
        typeset();
    }
});

function typeset()
{
    // Run a synchronous typeset operation in MathJax on the entire page
    MathJax.typeset();

    // For each item which has been typeset,
    $.each($('script[type="math/tex"]'), function(index, value)
    {
        if ($(value).parent().data('events') === undefined)
        {
            // ... append an onClick() event,
            $(value).parent().click(function()
            {
                if ($(value).parent().html().split($(value).html() || []).length - 1 === 1)
                {
                    // ... which will display the original LaTeX code with tags
                    $(value).parent().append(' \\$' + $(value).html() + '\\$');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Hearbeat function to typeset all LaTeX messages posted into the chat window
 */
function beat()
{
    // Create a timeout function using the configured interval
    setTimeout(() =>
    {
        typeset();

        if (update && !stop)
        {
            beat();
        }
    }, beatInterval);
};


I could not try to do anything because I do not currently know the
languages being used in the source code or in the answers I linked.
P.S. I think the problem might be in the following lines:
    // Create a script object to add the MathJax configuration  var script = document.createElement("script");  script.src =
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.2/es5/tex-svg.js";

    // Add MathJax to the page
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pzX2SlIf.jpg   [2]:
https://chrome-extension://jkohnpfocfllikbgkfdcghgjgejcfhjb/Jax.js

Could anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

If you uninstall (not disable) all your extensions do you still have this issue. You will want to specify more about your browser configuration if you want to report SE bug.

I removed all of them and still doesnt work. what do you mean when you say configuration? what do I have to do to provide it in the question?

Browser version, etc etc

ok I will see and add it. The browser version is Version 130.0.6723.70 (Official Build) ( 64 bit)

Have you checked w/ the plugin devs to see whether they support Manifest v3 (or whatever Chrome just implemented?)

yeah I wrote to the developer about this problem some days ago. Nobody has responded yet

if you are the extension author:

you can try to modify the manifest.json (allow your js domain). Here is a doc about the CSP: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/content-security-policy.

//manifest.json
"content_security_policy": { "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdnjs.cloudflare.com;", } 


the other way is to download the js file and import it locally.

if you are not the extension author, I think you should find a way to close the CSP checking. I don't know whether it is an option in chrome://settings. (not recommend)

This doesn’t really answer the authors question. Can you add specific guidance instructing how the author identifies and fixed their problem with their extension?

if you are the extension author, you can try to add this in manifest.json
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com;",
}

You should sit your answer instead of submitting a temporary comment.

ok, already add in answer, i found that the op is not the extension author, so there is not a solution for him. i think this problem need to be fixed by the extension author
